# Is there anyway I could get the href without using the tagnames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
def get_posts(driver):
posts = []
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"a")))

links_of_posts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')     # gets all elements with tag a and puts them in a list

for links in links_of_posts:
    post = Post()
    if hasattr(links,'href'):   #ERROR: no elements successfully enter the if, removing the if causes a stale element reference exception
        post.link = links.get_attribute('href')
        if '/p/' in post.link:
            posts.append(post)
```

The DOM structure should be something like this for all the elements, except the href differs:  ...

The page I used is an Instagram profile page, so https://www.instagram.com/definitelynotbot24/

The links_of_posts consist of elements that should have a hyperlink, but none of the elements seem to do so, any tips?

Comment: Can you share the DOM structure?

Comment: This better? (my first post btw)

Comment: It should be something like this for all the elements, except the href differs: <a href="/p/CSjpbtKFEYx/" tabindex="0" class=""> <div>...<div></a>

Comment: Is Page url public ? if not can you share relevant HTML code ?

Comment: Yes the page is public